# How to get size for subimage from SURF descriptor

Tags: descriptor, surf

I want to copy the part of an image which is descibed by a SURF descriptor. I know that the 9x9 filter in surf has a scale of 1.2. So if I have for example a descriptor with a scale of 1.2 is the part I can copy the 9x9 pixels around the descriptor point? And if I have a scale of 1.6 I would calculate the part with "9 / 1.2 * 1.6 = 12"? The subimage would be 12x12 pixels than?
On the other hand I read this in the OpenSURF documentation:

"The first step in extracting the SURF descriptor is to construct a square window around the interest point. This window contains the pixels which will form entries in the descriptor vector and is of size 20s, again where s refers to the detected scale."

So maybe I get the subimage if I take the 20*scale pixels around the descriptor point?
I don't know why it should be 20!? The first solution is more clear I guess...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to SURF original paper, I can answer you with two things:

1. The first solution you mention is the way to generate the filter size for an octave in SURF. However we don't have filter size 12x12. We just have {9x9,15x15,21x21,27x27},{15x15,27x27,..,..},{27x27,..},... It is not the region around the SURF key point for extracting the descriptor.
2. The sub image that covers a descriptor region is rotated window (based on dominant orientation) with the size 20*scale around the descriptor point. In my opinion, practical experiments allow the authors to pick that number (20). Similar to minimum Hessian threshold for eliminating non-SURF key points, they are heuristic method.

Answer (score 0):

If the implementation is exactly the one described in the original SURF paper, you have to use 20s. 9x9 is the starting filter size to detect interest points, but 20s is the window dimension to describe the area around an interest point.